# cmake transitive usage: propagate libs but keep headers private

Tags: cmake

If I create a static lib like this:

```
add_library(mylib STATIC
    mylib.h
    mylib.cpp
)
```

mylib.cpp includes headers from another library, let's call it `koko`.

Whoever uses mylib, needs to link to `koko` as well, but doesn't need to see the headers of `koko`.

But if I do this:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC koko)
```

Anyone using `mylib` will also see the headers of `koko`

How do I make it so that if a target uses `mylib` would link to `koko` but not see its headers?

Comment: So you want `target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE koko)`?

Comment: If I use PRIVATE, anyone using mylib will not link to koko

Comment: No. It will link to koko, just not see headers. Without propagating linking the whole idea of `link_libraries( PRIVATE )` would be useless.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and did work. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `PRIVATE` linking does. It propagates libraries and keeps headers private.

```
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE koko)
```